# Find $f(5)$ of a non-constant polynomial function $f(x)$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Suppose $f(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial such that $f(x^ 3) − f(x ^ 3 − 2) = f( x )\cdot f(x) + 12$ for all $x$. Find $f(5)$?

I find this problem on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Mathematics/Suppose-f-x-is-a-non-constant-polynomial-such-that-f-x-3-%E2%88%92-f-x-3-%E2%88%92-2-f-2-x-+-12-for-all-x-Find-f-5) just now, and I try to solve it but do not know where to start (every time I substitue a number  $a$ into the equation, I get three more unknown numbers). Would anyone give me any clue? Is there a general method to deal with this kind of problems?

Comment: Is $f^2(x)$ the square $f(x) \times f(x)$ or the composite $f\circ f(x)$?

Comment: @nik I think here $f^2(x)$ could be $f(x)\cdot f(x)$(edited), but I'm not sure...

Comment: Dude... this is a brilliant problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d$ be the degree of $f(x)$, $d > 0$. The degree of the RHS is $2d$. Now let's study the top degree terms of the LHS:

Write $f(x) = a x^d + b x^{d-1} + \dots$, $a\neq0$. then the LHS is (where $\dots$ are terms with degree $<3d-3$):
$$\begin{align}
ax^{3d} + b x^{3d-3} - \bigl( a (x^3-2)^d + b (x^3-2)^{d-1} \bigr) + \dots
& = ax^{3d} + bx^{3d-3} - \bigl( ax^{3d} - 2dax^{3d-3} + bx^{3d-3} \bigr) + \dots\\
&= -2dax^{3d-3} + \dots
\end{align}$$

So the LHS has degree 3d-3. Equating this with the degree of the RHS, the degree of $f(x)$ is 3. Now it's simply a matter of writing $f(x)$ explicitly, plugging into the original equation and solving for the coefficients.

Comment: Thank you! After going through a long calculation, I find $f(x) = 6(x^3-1)$, and therefore $f(5)=744$.